# Drupal Notice: Undefined Variable

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've just installed a new drupal theme to my site, and it was working just fine. All of a sudden, I'm getting this error on the main page:

> Notice: Undefined variable: author_name in include() (line 1354 of
>   /tpl/node--blog.tpl.php).

I check the line in my code, and I'm not sure why it is throwing me that error (especially since I know the variable is being used?)

```
<img alt='<?php print $author_name; ?>' src='<?php print $author_avatar_url; ?>' srcset='<?php print $author_avatar_url; ?>' class='avatar avatar-75 photo' height='75' width='75' />
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: probably whatever controller is handling that view is not properly passing the author_name into the view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print $author_name;` with `print $name;` to show author login name here.

You don't want username, but some custom field "Name"? In this case read [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1170380) - it have all info needed for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your print in 'if' statement

```
    <img alt='<?php
                if(!empty($author_name)): 
                    print $author_name; 
                endif;
                   ?>'
    src='<?php print $author_avatar_url; ?>' srcset='<?php print $author_avatar_url; ?>' class='avatar avatar-75 photo' height='75' width='75' />
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what Dr Holera said above, you need to wrap the code in an `if` statement, because you only want the code to execute on nodes that have that field.

This can often happen in a list of nodes where you have a non-required field (such as an image field). The code will run on all nodes visible on the page and give you an error of an `undefined variable` if any of those nodes do not have the non-required field filled in. So, when you pass it through the `if` statement, it means that code is only valid for those fields that are filled in.

Hope this helps you.